# Orthogonality of Bessel's functions with roots for derivatives

Tags: integration, orthogonality, bessel-functions

There exists an orthogonality relationship with Bessel's functions of the same order $n$:

$\int_0^1 r J_{n} (\lambda_{np}r) J_n (\lambda_{nq}r) dr = 0$ if $\lambda_{np} \neq \lambda_{nq}$

and

$\int_0^1 r J_{n} (\lambda_{np}r) J_n (\lambda_{nq}r) dr = \frac{1}{2} J^2_{n+1}$ if $\lambda_{np} = \lambda_{nq}$

where $\lambda_{np}$ represents the $p^\textrm{th}$ root of the $n^\textrm{th}$ Bessel function $J_{n}$ i.e., $J_n (\lambda_{np}) = 0$. Similarly, $\lambda_{nq}$ represents the $q^\textrm{th}$ root.

However, is there an orthogonality relationship involving the roots of the derivatives of Bessel functions? For example:

$\int_0^1 r J_{n} (\lambda_{np}r) J_n (\tau_{nq}r) dr =$  ???

where $\tau_{nq}$ is the $q^\textrm{th}$ root of the first derivative of $J_n(r)$ i.e., $\frac{d J_n}{dr} = 0 $ at $r = \tau_{nq}$.

Answer (score 2):

This was given as Problem 3.8 in Jackson's *Electrodynamics* book, 1st edition.  The derivation is fairly long, but is basically the same as the derivation of your reference orthogonality integral.  He gives the solution as:

$\int_0^a r J_\nu \left(\lambda _{\text{$\nu $p}} r \right) J_\nu \left(\lambda _{\text{$\nu $q}} r \right) \, dr =\frac{1}{2}
   a^2 \left(1-\frac{\nu ^2}{\lambda _{\text{$\nu $q}}^2}\right) J_{\nu }\left(\lambda _{\text{$\nu $q}}\right){}^2$

when $\lambda _{\text{$\nu $p}}=\lambda _{\text{$\nu $q}}$ and zero otherwise and where $\lambda _{\text{$\nu $q}}$ is the qth root of $\frac{dJ_{\nu }(r)}{dr}=0$